# What is the best C++ data structure that could be used for storing and managing a collection of integers?

Tags: c++, collections, integer

this is my first StackOverflow question so please let me know if I didn't follow community guidelines with this question and if I should delete it.

I got my first ever interview question and I got rejected because of my implementation.

The question is:

Design and implement a C++ class that stores a collection of integers. On construction, the collection should be empty. The same number may be stored more than once.

Implement the following methods:

1. Insert(int x).  Insert an entry for the value “x”.
2. Erase(int x).  Remove one entry with the value “x” (if one exists) from the collection.
3. Erase(int from, int to).  Remove all the entries with a value in the range [from, to).
4. Count(int from, int to).  Count how many entries have a value in the range [from, to).

I thought a good implementation would be to use linked lists since it uses non-contiguous memory and removing entries would not require shuffling a lot of data (like in vectors or arrays). However, I got feedback from the company saying my implementation was O(n^2) time complexity and was very inefficient so I was rejected. I don't want to repeat the same mistake if a similar question pops up in another interview so I'd like to know what is the best way to approach this question (a friend suggested using maps but he is also unsure).

My code is:

```
void IntegerCollector::insert(int x)
{
    entries.push_back(x);
}

void IntegerCollector::erase(int x)
{
    list<int>::iterator position = find(entries.begin(), entries.end(), x);
    if (position != entries.end())
        entries.erase(position);
}

void IntegerCollector::erase(int from, int to)
{
    list<int>::iterator position = entries.begin();

    while (position != entries.end())
    {
        if (*position >= from && *position <= to)
            position = entries.erase(position);
        else
            position++;
    }
}

int IntegerCollector::count(int from, int to)
{
    list<int>::iterator position = entries.begin();
    int count = 0;

    while (position != entries.end())
    {
        if (*position >= from && *position <= to)
            count++;

        position++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

The feedback mentioned that they would only hire candidates that can implement solutions with O(nlogn) complexity.

Comment: FWIW, `std::list` is normally not the data structure you want to use.  For the use case you have described a `std::multiset` sounds like what you want.  Almost all the operation will be `O(logN)` which isn't to bad.

Comment: Yours appears to be O(n)  which is better than O(nlogn)

Comment: @NathanOliver  with a std::list the order of the element is the one we want, not with any sorted container like _std::multiset_

Comment: @ben Yes but imagine he has an IntegerCollection of n items and he wants to erase all of that by calling erase for each element. That's a linear operation for each element which makes the time complexity quadratic.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes but he doesn't say it is allowed too, this is why I preferred to warn about that :-)

Comment: @0x499602D2 that's not in the spec. The requested operations are O(n). If you want an erase_all operation or erase_many operation then they too can be implemented efficiently.

Comment: This is a well-composed question, but I suspect that it is _primarily opinion based_.  I'm not sure any of us could tell you what implementation your interviewer would have considered "best".

Comment: I mean, big O is misleading here because it's a toy example, but the point is I suspect that the answer was rejected because it's naïve rather than because it's actually wrong as such. using a list to store integers is inefficient in terms of memory and in modern architectures that's likely to dominate the big O.

Comment: As Ben says, your algorithm is not `O(n^2)`, but `O(n)`.

Comment: @Ben: which data structure would be better? `set` and `unordered_set` are even more inefficient for storing integers than a list.

Comment: I think you can easily implement this using `std::multiset` and a few functions from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Judy arrays are made specifically for integer sets. They are very compact and fast.

Comment: @NathanOliver Or as I like to say, "No matter what the question, a linked list is the wrong answer"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key consideration here is that integers of the same value are indistinguishable. Thus, all you need to do is store a **count of each distinct value in the container**.

Then, you can just use a `std::map<int, size_t>` as backing structure that maps each integer (key) to the number of times it exists in your data structure (value = count).

Inserting and erasing single elements is just incrementing and decrementing (possibly removing in the latter case) values for the given key (both `O(log(distinct_values_in_container))` for finding the key).

Since `std::map` is ordered, you can use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` to do binary search, so finding the keys in [from, to) is very efficient (finding the range is also `O(log(distinct_values_in_container))`). Erasing them or summing their counts is easy then (runtime is more complicated here).

---

If you want to gain extra credit, it will pay to understand the limitations of asymptotic runtimes. Consider these points:

What these asymptotic runtimes mean in practice depends a lot on the usage pattern. If no duplicates are ever inserted, we are at `O(n)`, but you can also get arbitrarily good times (in terms of `n` = number of insertions) if there are lots of identical elements (for example, if each key has `O(exp(n))` values then `O(distinct_values_in_container) = O(log(n))`). In the extreme case that all involved integers are the same, all operations are `O(1)`.

As an interviewee, I would also talk about whether these asymptotic runtimes are meaningful in practice. It may be that the map's tree structure (which is toxic for the cache and branch predictor) loses to a simple `std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>>` (if erasure is always in bulk) or even a `std::vector<size_t>` (if the keys are "dense") for the given application.

---

I think your main mistake (and why you were rejected) is not realizing that there is no need to store each inserted integer separately. You unfortunately also seem to have missed the possibility of keeping the list sorted, but I don't see where the `O(n^2)` comes from.

Answer (score 11):

If you were being hired for a role that didn't require any previous programming experience then I would not have rejected you on that code sample alone.

Using a `std::list` was an interesting choice and showed you had thought about this. The fact that you used a C++ standard library container rather than trying to build this from a lower level is a yes-hire flag for me. With your approach (1) is fast, but (2), (3), and (4) will be slow. In the absence of any other information you ought to arrange things so that reading (including querying) data is faster than writing. Your approach has this the other way round. Sometimes though that is what you want - for example when taking measurements real-time you’d want the data dump stage to be as fast as possible at the expense of anything else. For that application your solution would be difficult to beat!

Reservations, but by no means red lines:

An integer does not mean an `int`. In the absence of being able to clarify, build your class on

```
template<typename Y> std::map<Y, std::size_t>
```

where `Y` is an integral type. Note the use of `std::size_t` for the counter. It counts the number of times a particular `Y` is present.

Include some program comments next time.

Don't use `using namespace std;`. Although tutorials do for clarity, professional programmers don't.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't include comments here but I included them in the code I submitted. I won't use namespace std from now on. Could you clarify what you mean by "big hire flag"? Should I have done a linked list using structs?

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for _why_ `using namespace std;` is bad practice.

Comment: Can you qualify why using an STL container is a flag? Seems like the smart thing to do here. From the problem statement, nothing other than operational parameters are given, so why re-invent the wheel? You save the company time and write better code with this. I would only reinvent the wheel if I knew I could save resources on a limited system or make it faster for a niche use case.

Comment: @TechnoSam it says 'hire flag', that's a good thing not a bad.

Comment: Yes indeed: a flag for hire is a good thing! Sorry to have caused confusion.

Comment: `using namespace std;` can be perfectly fine in certain situations. Like in the situations described by some non-professional programmers called Bjarne Stroustrup/Herb Sutter in C++ Core Guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `map<int,size_t>` the `int` is for value, the `size_t` is for count.

If you need to implement the code, you should choose a Balanced Binary Tree to get to 'log N' complexity.

so you have the following node:

```
struct Node
{
  int key;
  size_t count;
  Node *left, *right; 
  size_t leftNodesCount, rightNodesCount;
};
```

`leftNodesCount` and `rightNodesCount` are ment to indicate how good is the balance, so any insertion and deletion is changing it all the way to the root. a balanced tree is when all over the tree leftNodesCount and rightNodesCount are almost equal (mean difference is not more than 1. but you can set the tolerance to some higher value like 2 or 3)

Now you should implement `Insert`, `Delete`, and `Balance` methods.

To balance a Balanced Tree, you should rotate the unbalanced nodes, Rotate left means replace node by the node's right, and add the node to left, Rotate right is the same operation in the other direction.

Balance complicity is also 'log N'. note that after insertions and deletions you should call to balance in manner to keep the complicity of the tree something about 'log N'

Answer (score 0):

memory management is most important part of C++. It is a fact that accessing contiguous memory is several times faster than non continuous. For your problem vector  will be more efficient than list . Problem with list is non contiguous memory allocation which causes lot of cache miss.

That's why expert says "avoid list as much as you can"

Comment: `std::vector` may be better than `std::list` for this, but its asymptotic complexity is worse than existing answers.